# Indent many lines in Theorem environment

Tags: indentation, theorems

If I want to indent the first line in the `theorem` environment I just write `\indent`. How may I indent several lines - a paragraph - in this environment?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newbox\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnCornerHgt
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$\ulcorner$}
\global\gnCornerHgt=\ht\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnArgHgt
\def\Godelnum #1{%
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$#1$}%
\gnArgHgt=\ht\gnBoxA%
\ifnum     \gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt \gnArgHgt=0pt%
\else \advance \gnArgHgt by -\gnCornerHgt%
\fi \raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\ulcorner$} \box\gnBoxA %
\raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\urcorner$}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}(The Carnap-G\"{o}del Diagonal Lemma)\vspace{4pt}\\
If $\Psi(x)$ is a formula with the variable $x$ free then there is a formula $\Phi$ such that all desistances of $\vdash(\Phi\leftrightarrow\Psi\Godelnum{\Phi})$ hold.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you shouldn't need to use `\indent` ever in latex. You give no clue how your theorem environmnt is defined (theorem? amsthm? ntheorem? etc, in most theorem packages the theorem text is set as a list item so its left margin can be specified, as for a list when setting up the environment

Comment: I use amsthm.

In this case I wanted to indent the two lines of the theorem. Is it wrong?

Comment: Do you mean *all* lines of the theorem or *some* lines?

Comment: All, i.e. both of the lines in this case.

Comment: @Bernard Why does your last suggestion not compile for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, if I've well understood what you want, with `ntheorem`. I loaded it with option `amsthm` (compatibility mode). I defined a new theorem style, `plainindent`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newbox\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnCornerHgt
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$\ulcorner$}
\global\gnCornerHgt=\ht\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnArgHgt
\def\Godelnum #1{%
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$#1$}%
\gnArgHgt=\ht\gnBoxA%
\ifnum \gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt \gnArgHgt=0pt%
\else \advance \gnArgHgt by -\gnCornerHgt%
\fi \raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\ulcorner$} \box\gnBoxA %
\raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\urcorner$}}



\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
  \theoremindent1em
  \makeatletter
  \newtheoremstyle{plainindent}%
  {\item[\hskip-\theoremindent\hskip\labelsep\relax\theorem@headerfont##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip-\theoremindent\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
  \makeatother

\theoremstyle{plainindent}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{theorem}(The Carnap-G\"{o}del Diagonal Lemma)\vspace{4pt}\ If $\Psi(x)$ is a formula with the variable $x$ free then there is a formula $\Phi$ such that all desistances of $\vdash(\Phi\leftrightarrow\Psi\Godelnum{\Phi})$ hold. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. No, I want  Theorem (The Carnap-Gödel Diagonal Lemma) leftadjusted and then the content of the theorem indented on lines below Theorem  (The Carnap-Gödel Diagonal Lemma) .

Comment: That point wasn't clear. Do you want *all* the subsequent lines to be indented?

Comment: I propose a solution, defining a `plainindent` theoremstyle. Is it more like what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want all the succeeding lines indented.

Comment: Now I am not able to compile ...

Comment: Why does your last suggestion not compile for me?

Comment: Did you compile exactly the code I posted?

Comment: Yes. I just copy and glue the present answer as posted, and it does not compile.

Comment: Is your installation up-to-date? Could you post the `.log`?

Comment: I do not know what .log is. Let me consult with an assistant. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30493/discussion-between-bernard-and-frode-bjordal).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have space commands within the document body, also theorem commands have an optional argument to take the title.

`amsthm` doesn't directly support an indented style but it is easy enough to include the paragraph settings along with the body font as below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newbox\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnCornerHgt
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$\ulcorner$}
\global\gnCornerHgt=\ht\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnArgHgt
\def\Godelnum #1{%
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$#1$}%
% no % needed on following line
\gnArgHgt=\ht\gnBoxA
% Space needed (in general) after pt so there should
% not be a % on following line (or leave space before %)
\ifnum     \gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt \gnArgHgt=0pt
% no % needed on following line
\else \advance \gnArgHgt by -\gnCornerHgt
% no % needed on following line
\fi \raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\ulcorner$} \box\gnBoxA
\raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\urcorner$}}


\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{zz}% name
  {3pt}%       Space above
  {3pt}%       Space below
  {\addtolength\leftskip{\parindent}%
   \addtolength\@totalleftmargin{\parindent}%
   \addtolength\linewidth{-\parindent}%
   \itshape}%          Body font
  {-\parindent}%          Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {}%         Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%      Space after theorem head
  {}%          Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal' )
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{zz}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X


\begin{theorem}[The Carnap-G\"{o}del Diagonal Lemma]
If $\Psi(x)$ is a formula with the variable $x$ free then there is a formula $\Phi$ such that all desistances of $\vdash(\Phi\leftrightarrow\Psi\Godelnum{\Phi})$ hold.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```